# How an I insert variables at a specific place in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, insert

What is the best method to take a 'template' string and insert information into it.

For example:

```
var templateString = "Hello {name1}, my name is {name2}";
var name1 = "Phil";
var name2 = "Amy";
```

Would there be an easy name to insert the values where the variable name surrounded by braces is? I need this to work not only for this example (so doing it by a fixed index is not an option) but for any given template string and any given number of variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ES2015 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). But, the variables should be defined before using them.

```js
var name1 = "Phil";
var name2 = "Amy";
var templateString = `Hello ${name1}, my name is ${name2}`;

console.log(templateString);
document.body.innerHTML = templateString;
```

For pre-ES2015, you can use regex to replace the variables. For this, an object having the search-replace values can be created and [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with function as parameter can be used.

The regex [`\{([^}]*)\}`](https://regex101.com/r/eJ8iB4/1) can be used to match the strings which are surrounded by the curly brackets.

```js
// Create an object of the key-value of search-replace
var obj = {
    name1: "Phil",
    name2: "Amy"
};

var templateString = "Hello {name1}, my name is {name2}";

// Use replace with callback function
var result = templateString.replace(/\{([^}]*)\}/g, function($0, $1) {
    return obj[$1] || $0; // If replacement found in object use that, else keep the string as it is
});

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `\{`: Match `{` bracket literal
2. `([^}]*)`: Match anything other than `}` zero or more number of times and add this in the first captured group.
3. `\}`: Match `}` bracket literal
4. `g`: Global flag. Match all possible strings that follows this pattern.

**Note:** `$0` is the complete string i.e. `{foo}` and `$1` is the first captured group `foo`.

Comment: +1 I was about to write almost this exact answer. You can also use `window` or `this` for the object for global or scoped contexts

Comment: @ThomasZwaagstra Yes, you can. But it is considered as bad practice and I don't recommend that. Using an object is better way.

Comment: Would you consider the prototype pattern bad practice? If you're already in an object context, you may already have a viable object with your variables set

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has string interpolation, you can do it like this

```js
var name1 = "Phil";
var name2 = "Amy";
var templateString = `Hello ${name1}, my name is ${name2}`;

document.write(templateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the javascript function replace: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

so your code would be:

```
var templateString = "Hello {name1}, my name is {name2}";
var name1 = "Phil";
var name2 = "Amy";

templateString = templateString.replace('{name1}', name1);
templateString = templateString.replace('{name2}', name2);
```

please let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Much better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Also FWIW, the code shown in this answer will only replace the **first** occurrence of each token. If anything is used more than once, it won't get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

In ES5, you could use String.replace:

```
var templateString = "Hello {name1}, my name is {name2}";
var name1 = "Phil";
var name2 = "Amy";

templateString.replace(/\{([^}]*)\}/g, function (m, v) { return eval(v) || m; })
```

Note that the use of eval is not recommended. If you set the names in an object, you could do this:

```
var templateString = "Hello {name1}, my name is {name2}";
var names = {};
names.name1 = "Phil";
names.name2 = "Amy";

templateString.replace(/\{([^}]*)\}/g, function (m, v) { return names[v] || m; })
```